# Typescript object variable reference

Tags: typescript

I have defined a static object :

```
const instruments = {
    "guitar": {
        tunings: ["E","A","D","G","B","E"]
    },
    "ukulele": {
        tunings: ["G","C","E","A"]
    },
    "baritone": {
        tunings: ["D","G","B","E"]
    },
    "mandolin": {
        tunings: ["G","G","D","D","A","A","E","E"]
    },
   "bass": {
        tunings: ["E","A","D","G"]
    }
}
```

and want to call a function with the name of the instrument I am referencing to obtain appropriate 'tunings' array :

```
    constructor(canvas : HTMLCanvasElement, tuningName : string, startFret = 0, noFrets : number) : any {
        const tuningsArr = instruments[tuningName].tunings;
        ...
}
```

however VSCode tells me that's not valid Typescript. How can I achieve getting a reference to the correct tunings array from the passed string?

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting? Try `(instruments[tuningName] as any).tunings` and see if it works.

Comment: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type..." is the error. Typecasting to 'any' seems like a bit of a hack, but is a potential solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do that.

You can use the type inferred for the `instruments` const, but to do that, you have to tell TypeScript that the state of the `instruments` object is constant using `as const`:

```typescript
const instruments = {
    "guitar": {
        tunings: ["E","A","D","G","B","E"]
    },
    "ukulele": {
        tunings: ["G","C","E","A"]
    },
    "baritone": {
        tunings: ["D","G","B","E"]
    },
    "mandolin": {
        tunings: ["G","G","D","D","A","A","E","E"]
    },
   "bass": {
        tunings: ["E","A","D","G"]
    }
} as const;
// ^^^^^^^
```

Then, constrain the type of `tuningName` to `keyof typeof instruments` (a valid key for the type that `instruments` has), requiring that it be a valid key for that (now constant) object:

```typescript
class Example {
    constructor(canvas : HTMLCanvasElement, tuningName : keyof typeof instruments, startFret = 0, noFrets : number) : any {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        const tuningsArr = instruments[tuningName].tunings;
        // ...
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlpKAnArgWwKZihGBeGAbwCgYyYAiAcxTigEMkKAuI08jqFMBKiVgNoUAohQA0FAILiKAERkBxGQCEZogLrsyAXzFbKKANYoANhjMs2HTt178YQpRIDCamdM0dd+igCNGdOAYliTW5Fw8YHyCcooqbp7k3hwUaPRgACYgJggh+jaR0Q4UTiUy8hIVUu5uEhr6yWR+9BAQeWFkEXYxohLSlXGJOsTaMC0woIgA3MTEwCYtuMIAHvRoAA5mVuST0KjAUCBIABQA9ABUwOkAbuOsABIAKgCyADLONy3CZpjYYjDnU5dKIAOTWGBgrEMGAAniAAGYwKAw9YYBHwRCoX44C7-aCMKAAMSQGFgBAADP8wCBiaTcKwwOhfBgkICAJSQsZgGHbMK7WDAviSJBIfAYvboLA4ASCsGYdQAOkFEBmHRgp1OMAV2oaI1mYAwAHcYCs1psMMdqLQGEw2VN1ZqAOpHQwQYgG42mjZmS1HdJUYJ2h0wWQgDAQMAAclghpd-wABhQ-VFgvH4BHo2MYLcchkYNCYUA)

Alternatively, you could declare types explicitly and assign `instruments` the type for instruments:

```typescript
interface Tuning {
    tunings: string[];   // You could even nail this type down more if you wanted
}
interface Instruments {
    guitar: Tuning;
    ukulele: Tuning;
    baritone: Tuning;
    mandolin: Tuning;
    bass: Tuning;
}
const instruments: Instruments = {
    "guitar": {
        tunings: ["E","A","D","G","B","E"]
    },
    "ukulele": {
        tunings: ["G","C","E","A"]
    },
    "baritone": {
        tunings: ["D","G","B","E"]
    },
    "mandolin": {
        tunings: ["G","G","D","D","A","A","E","E"]
    },
   "bass": {
        tunings: ["E","A","D","G"]
    }
};
```

Then it's `keyof Instruments` rather than `keyof typeof instruments`:

```typescript
class Example {
    constructor(canvas : HTMLCanvasElement, */tuningName : keyof Instruments, startFret = 0, noFrets : number) : any {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        const tuningsArr = instruments[tuningName].tunings;
        // ...
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoFcSgObIN4BQyxyYmOAzgFzIVhQ4DaAugNwkD0HyAmgPbpkCAQBsAJsggA3CCGQg4wEaQAWwCqQCeABxRi+AdzkBbPlBTAYyTQOQG44CGIIBfAqEixEKAJIg6UOjGsmAahCTI2OjAYHBQNBhYINisRCToANboIhA5CeTJqREARnExfCAQ+UkpacTGDvoioNU4RSSlFNRoBbVuwv5gyKABQSHdfqPB4BoAvPh1yABEUTFxSzThESRkNd2MSwCiSwA0SwCCp0sAIlcA4lcAQlfHzIsuJ4tLmdm5EBsLbY7Xr7JYPM4AYReV0ubwiHy+pQYYAq-02iwiu0oNAOtzO4KWzzOr3enwiSwaICaoABWyBWOSoIJBLxNxh7OJ0LhJARJCWnQotIxwL2OKOHLZ+KW3OIbhcqQICBEcC6yEOAA84MZtDlASQBqMECioAAKDgAKgQDikKuQNAAEqgALIAGQh1pVhxy0zAJ2Q5o4DOwADktSgaBkIDYrJN6GMZha-XQ4mAAGLmIbzAAMfpAfHTEFCdvkQWK0ADAEpiw5NHqgQahkGKOcoFBkPMRnGfRRGEHQ8FmAA6JvtIFcZCDyfvVwEAiVAxqzXanImlbRWJQJYV9jjgDqZgyFDnEAXGq1Oogq7MDmw-23yHH1z4EAoIAA5EMDAe-QADJbX5J-h-YZXw-ZA4GQG1mgkSNNCAA)